# How to print text in web browser by using Play 2 framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am newbie to Play 2 framework. How can I print 'HELLO WORLD' text in web browser without using any view file.

I have setup route file as below :

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET /                        controllers.Mantra.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

My controller is as below:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import java.util.*;
import views.html.*;


public class Mantra extends Controller  {


  public static Result index(){
     return ok(index.render("HELLO WOLRD"));

  }
```

}

I have tried many times, but it is still showing default page. Can some one guide what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
public static Result index(){
     return ok("HELLO WORLD");

}
```

ie, call the [ok() method](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/play/mvc/Results.html#ok%28java.lang.String%29) which take only a String as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It displays always welcome page, because in your `views/index.scala.html` file you have still this line:

```
@play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")
```

It loads the welcome page from the Play. After removing it you can start using this view, as your any other view.

Of course for displaying *saute* text **nico_ekito's** solution is better, than rendering it via views.